# MySQL function returns 'cached' result when called directly by Doctrine connection

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I have a MySQL function which is used to number the submitted documents. It is implemented directly in MySQL server (pretty much to avoid deadlocks, concurrency and similar nice things). Table stores the last used number for particular document key, and function takes this number, increments it and returns back to Symfony application which assigns this to document.

```
DELIMITER $$
FUNCTION `NEXT_NUMBER`(requested_key VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
    DECLARE nextNumber INT;

    INSERT INTO `document_numbers` (key, last_number) VALUES (requested_key, 1)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE last_number = last_number+1;
        SELECT last_number INTO nextNumber FROM `document_numbers` WHERE key = requested_key

   RETURN nextNumber;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

In application this function is called in separate Doctrine connection, which is not used for standard entity and database operations.

```
public function getNewNumber(string $key) : int
{
    $this->connection->setAutoCommit(false);

    try {
        $this->connection->beginTransaction();
        $statement = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT NEXT_NUMBER(:key);");
        $statement->bindValue('series', $key);
        $statement->execute();
        $this->connection->commit();

        $number = (int) $statement->fetchColumn();

        $this->connection->close();
    } catch (\Throwable $e) {
        $this->connection->rollBack();
        $this->connection->close();
        throw $e;
    }

    return $number;
}
```

Now problematic part is that

```
$number = (int) $statement->fetchColumn();
```

returns the same value over multiple HTTP requests. Pretty much same behavior as if the result value would be cached. This behavior is not repeating 100% of time. I tried to add `SQL_NO_CACHE` to `SELECT` query to no avail.

Setup:

- MySQL 5.7
- Symfony 3.4
- PHP 7.1
- Doctrine/DBAL 2.7
- OroPlatform 3.1

Doctrine config:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection:   default
        connections:
            default:
                server_version: '5.7'
                driver:       "%database_driver%"
                host:         "%database_host%"
                port:         "%database_port%"
                dbname:       "%database_name%"
                user:         "%database_user%"
                password:     "%database_password%"
                charset:      UTF8MB4
                mapping_types:
                    bit: boolean
                    json: string
            secondary: # this one is used for $this->connection->prepare("SELECT NEXT_NUMBER(:key);");
                server_version: '5.7'
                driver:       "%database_driver%"
                host:         "%database_host_secondary%" # this is simply pointing to 127.0.1.1
                port:         "%database_port%"
                dbname:       "%database_name%"
                user:         "%database_user%"
                password:     "%database_password%"
                charset:      UTF8MB4
```

There is no MySQL/Doctrine caching setup present.

Comment: Try calling flush() after commit

Comment: there is not `flush()` method on `$this->connection`, it is `Doctrine\DBAL\Connection`

Answer (score 0):

So one solution is to turn auto-commit back on `$this->connection->setAutoCommit(true);`, although this definitely was not the case when had this same piece of code on Symfony 2.8 and previous version of Doctrine.

Also the `"SELECT NEXT_NUMBER(:key);"` was actually returning incremented number and not some 'cached' version, but not committing it to database table after it was incremented.

I don't know how this was happening since `$this->connection->commit();` is clearly executed and does not throw any errors. Maybe MySQL/PHP/Doctrine is somehow creating separate transaction for the operation. However, so far doesn't seem to encounter any problems with autocommit on, so the question itself is probably solved, though any input and description of the behavior would be appreciated.